# Assembly Code to C, what are the arguments in the C code that will make the Assembly code

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, x86, att

So I just signed up for this online course, and this was part of my first assignment, I have already found the missing pieces in the assembly code and have gotten this far.

This is the assembly code:

```
0x08048394 <call1+0>:  push   %ebp
0x08048395 <call1+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048397 <call1+3>:  sub    $0x10,%esp
0x0804839a <call1+6>:  mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x0804839d <call1+9>:  mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
0x080483a1 <call1+13>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
0x080483a4 <call1+16>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%ecx
0x080483a7 <call1+19>: mov    (%ecx,%edx,4),%eax
0x080483aa <call1+22>: mov    0x10(%ebp),%ebx
0x080483ad <call1+25>: mov    (%ebx,%edx,4),%esi
0x080483b0 <call1+28>: cmp    %esi,%eax
0x080483b2 <call1+30>: jle    0x80483b9 <call1+37>
0x080483b4 <call1+32>: mov    %eax,(%ebx,%edx,4)
0x080483b7 <call1+35>: jmp    0x80483be <call1+42>
0x080483b9 <call1+37>: mov    %esi,(%ecx,%edx,4)
0x080483bc <call1+40>: mov    %esi,%eax
0x080483be <call1+42>: pop    %ebx
0x080483bf <call1+43>: pop    %esi
0x080483c0 <call1+44>: add    $0x8,%esp
0x080483c3 <call1+47>: leave
0x080483c4 <call1+48>: ret
```

**My question is, what arguments in the following C code snippet will lead to the above assembly code :**

```
int main(){

int a1[] = {10, 12, 3, 4, 25};

int a2[] = {9, 28, 7, 16, 5};

call1(_________________________________);

}
```

**I think its just a1 and a2 but I am not sure which is why I need some help.**
This assembly code to me looks like it may just be swapping the values of the two arrays...
Am I right, or completely off?

Comment: Didn't figure out the whole thing, but you've got 3 positive offsets relative to `(%ebp)` so I'd say there are three arguments to that function.

Comment: The function also appears to have a return value being set at `call+40`.  `eax` is getting assigned something.

Comment: Thank you that's a step closer than I was. I appreciate it!

Comment: Im wondering if the three parameters are a1, a2 and an int for traversal?

Comment: This question is ill-formed: *"what arguments in the following C code snippet will lead to the above assembly code?"* - any argument will lead to that code. That is the code of the function itself, it will always be the same no matter what arguments you pass to it. If you want to figure out which arguments are passed, you need to look at the assembly code of the caller (`main`)!

Comment: The sad truth is, you can't tell from this asm source. You'd need to code of `main`. You can make intelligent guesses but that is all. Like, two arguments are obviously pointers and you can guess they are probably `a1` and `a2` but you don't know which is which, and they can also be something like `a1 + 3` or even totally unrelated. Also there is no loop in the code so it's clearly not processing the whole arrays. You can also see the first argument is used as an index but you don't know the value.

Comment: I wasnt given anything else clue wise for the main except the snippet provided. I'm afraid you have confirmed my fears and this is a bit of a hopeless assignment.

Comment: As for `call1` itself, it looks like it's comparing the items at the given index in the two arrays, and copies the larger one to the smaller one and returns it as well.

Comment: @Jester, that was my assumption too, I was hoping there was a way to detect the integer used the swap. I can see that the values 16 and 4 seem to swap which would suggest the last parameter is int 3 right?

Comment: Yeah well that's additional information you did not provide. In that case `call1(3, a1, a2)` could work but `call1(3, a2, a1)` would work equally well as would `call1(0, a1+3, a2+3)` or similar. Note it does not **swap** the values, it should just overwrite the `4` with the `16`.

Comment: To be fair I just noticed... I think I will work on the assumption call1(3, a2, a1) because I think line 3 suggests 16 was stored first...

Comment: You may gain in reading this article which describes the C calling convention that requires the caller and callee to do specific things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @Tarik, thank you! I found that very interesting and useful!

Comment: I'm curious what compiler version/options produced that asm.  Saving ESI and EBX with `mov` relative to ESP is unusual, and may indicate some old GCC(?) version that tunes for CPUs where `push` was somewhat slow.  And also where `-fomit-frame-pointer` was *not* on by default with optimization enabled, since this doesn't look like full debug-mode (only 1 load of anything, not reload every use).  Clang is the closest I've come on https://godbolt.org/z/xTqjez1xo, GCC likes to left-shift index once instead of using indexed addressing modes.  Maybe Godbolt just doesn't have an old enough GCC.

Comment: But use of `leave` instead of `pop %ebp` is usually a sign of GCC.  And this code has some missed optimizations that can act as further fingerprints of compiler version / options.  e.g. `add    $0x8,%esp` is totally pointless given that `leave` is the next instruction, which doesn't care about the previous value of ESP.   (And the specific register choices, and branch layouts, are also going to be specific to a compiler.)  (Code in my previous comment's link is from Marco's answer, and a ternary attempt to make it one expression because I was thinking -O0 because of the frame pointer.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe our class uses a 32bit machine and gcc... its probably very out of date though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, this question is ill-formed: *"what arguments in the following C code snippet will lead to the above assembly code?"* - any argument will lead to that code. That is the code of the function itself, it will always be the same no matter what arguments you pass to it. If you want to figure out which arguments are passed, you need to look at the assembly code of the caller (`main`).

However, even without the full code of `main`, with the part of C source that you have and the assembly of the function we can infer the following:

1. The function is passed 3 arguments, as we can see it referencing `0x8(%ebp)`, `0xc(%ebp)` and `0x10(%ebp)`. These arguments are in order first, second and third.
2. The first argument (offset `0x8` from `ebp`) is used as an index, as we can see from:

   ```
   mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   mov    0xc(%ebp),%ecx
   mov    (%ecx,%edx,4),%eax
   ```
3. The other two arguments (offsets `0xc` and `0x10`) are treated as pointers to arrays and indexed with the first.

Given the above, a fair reconstruction of the code would be the following:

```
int call1(int index, int *a1, int *a2) {
    int eax, esi;

    eax = a1[index];
    esi = a2[index];

    if (eax <= esi) {
        a1[index] = esi;
        eax = esi;
    } else {
        a2[index] = eax;
    }

    return eax;
}
```

> This assembly code to me looks like it may just be swapping the values of the two arrays... Am I right, or completely off?

Yep, that seems right to me. Of course in reality we do not know what is actually passed to the function, but if the call made in `main` is the following:

```c
call1(some_index, a1, a2);
```

Then the function takes `a1`, `a2` and some index, and it checks if the element of `a1` at the given index is lower than or equal to the element of `a2` at the same index. If so, the first element is overridden by the second, otherwise the second element is overridden by the first. In any case, the function is returning the value of the largest element.

**Note that** we actually have no idea if the first argument passed is `a1` or `a2`. It could be either way, or it could even be `a1 + something` and `a2 + something_else`. What the exact parameters are can only be determined by looking at the full code (C or assembly) of `main`!

Comment: Thank you very much for the breakdown I really appreciate it. I could only initially see that a swap was occurring but not how it was done. I see that you used pointers, is there a particular reason? Something in the assembly that implies pointers?

Comment: @Struggle_Bus well, yes, this: `mov (%ecx,%edx,4),%eax` is a classical indexing into an array (of elements of 4 bytes) given a pointer. In this case the pointer would be in `ecx` and the index in `edx`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you very much for the help in understanding this!